# Get group membership fast

Tags: .net, windows, membership, active-directory-group

I am trying to figure out whether the current windows user either is local administrator or can use UAC to "attain" that group membership.

What I've come up so far looks like this:

```
var adminIdentifier = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544");
var current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
bool isAdmin = current.Groups.Contains(adminIdentifier);
bool canBeAdmin = isAdmin;

if (!isAdmin)
{
    var adminGroupName = adminIdentifier.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
    adminGroupName = adminGroupName.Substring(adminGroupName.LastIndexOf('\\'));
    string path = "WinNT://./" + adminGroupName + ",group";

    using (DirectoryEntry groupEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path))
    {
      foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)groupEntry.Invoke("Members"))
      {
        using (DirectoryEntry memberEntry = new DirectoryEntry(member))
        {
              object obVal = memberEntry.Properties["objectSid"].Value;
              SecurityIdentifier sid = null;
              if (null != obVal)
              {
                 sid = new SecurityIdentifier((Byte[])obVal,0);
              }

              canBeAdmin = Equals(current.User, sid);
              if (canBeAdmin)
                break;
        }
     }
   }
 }
 Console.WriteLine(canBeAdmin +" "+isAdmin);
```

This solution takes a few milliseconds to compute. Much faster than the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement based approach I tried before.

There is one last thing that bothers me, though. I have to translate the SecurityIdentifier of the admin group to the name. There ought to be a way to get
the DirectoryEntry directly by using the SID. According to Google, this should work:

```
string path = "LDAP://<SID=" + adminIdentifier.ToString() + ">";
```

However, this does not seem to work. Any idea how the syntax should look like?

Comment: A few questions before I might give another answer... a) What version of Windows are you using?, b) Can you confirm that adminIdentifier.ToString() evaluates to "S-1-5-32-544", c) Are you getting any specific error when querying LDAP?

Comment: a) Windows Vista Ultimate. b) yes. c) Error says that the specified domain could not be found. My computer is not in any domain, so that might be a clue. However, I need a solution that works regardless whether the computer is in a domain or not.

Comment: The syntax is good.. And I know it works, because i'm using it too. I guess it does not work for knownsids

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole.aspx) ?

```
WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
wp.IsInRole(new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544"));
wp.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

Comment: WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole() returns false for the administrator group when running in non-elevated mode. That's why I have to determine group membership in another way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [GetAuthorizationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups.aspx) on the UserPrincipal object corresponding to the current user?  You may have to check whether the user is directly in the local administrators group or whether the local administrators group contains any of the authorization groups that the user is in if GetAuthorizationGroups doesn't include machine-local groups.  I haven't tried this with a machine context so I'm not sure whether you'd need to also search the domain context for the latter match if it doesn't compute the local group membership using domain/global/universal groups when using the machine context.

Comment: GetAuthorizationGroups() yields the same result, unfortunately with the same (lack of) performance.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want, unless I misunderstand:

```
var groupName = adminIdentifier.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
```

Comment: My problem statement is probably not clear enough :-)
I have: a SecurityIdentifier for a windows group.
I need: the DirectoryEntry for that group
Currently, I have to convert the SID to a name. I would like to get rid of that conversion.